# Python regex groupDict with repetitions of groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-regex

Wondering if there is a function such as `match.groupdict()` that catches repetition similar to `match.captures` function.

When I run this code:

```
import regex

test = regex.compile("(?P<a>a)*(?P<b>b)*(?P<c>c)*")
test.match("aabbbcc").groupdict()
```

I get:

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
```

what I would like is something like that:

```
{'a': ['a', 'a'], 'b': ['b', 'b', 'b'], 'c': ['c', 'c']}
```

Is there a function to do so or should I just do it by hand myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
import regex
test=regex.compile("(?P<a>a)*(?P<b>b)*(?P<c>c)*")
print ( test.match("aabbbcc").capturesdict() )
# => {'a': ['a', 'a'], 'b': ['b', 'b', 'b'], 'c': ['c', 'c']}
```

Or, if you need to match the entire string with this pattern, replace `.match` with `.fullmatch`:

```py
test.fullmatch("aabbbcc").capturesdict()
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##JcsxDsIwDADAva@IMtkdsrCW8AW@YBurjUQaKzUSvD6osN1y9vGt7ZcxSrXWPXRd9T25Hn79MUmrVp4KEW73hTLhfIIz/yFZcI44WS@7BwjnTJVcNohEzCwSMQmZv7oejyIOGHCMLw).

See the [PyPi regex module documentation](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#added-capturesdict-hg-issue-86):

> `capturesdict` returns a dict of the named groups and lists of all the captures of those groups.